# Replicate Cross Object Formulas with Apex Framework

Tags: apex, formula, cross-object, framework

Thought I would ask the question before I start creating!

We have hit the number of references limitation on a few objects - you know the 10 references one which can be raised to 15 (but that's as far as Salesforce will go). Therefore, we need to use Apex to set fields which would normally be dynamic via cross-object formula field.

I am looking for some start point and is agnostic so that I can extend into any before insert or before update DML. Will probably look to add Custom Metadata Type into the mix. Just want to save a bit of time if anyone has anything.

Many thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't `Process Builder` meet your needs?

Comment: The limitation extends to workflow rules so would expect it to be there with process builder - could be wrong though. Worth checking

Comment: You can at least perform more actions (or at least apply more criteria) in PB than a single WFR, so you can get more bang for your buck there. You can also invoke apex from PB flow. Might give you more flexibility than pure triggers, though it doesn't sound like criteria are a huge deal. I guess just checking if the relevant field has changed?

Comment: Spot on Adrain. I am hope for something which we can plug into our existing trigger framework. Then we only need to CMT records for each additional field which surfaces.

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using, but [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) can really help with the filtering aspect.